# How to implement mustache lambda in java

Tags: java, mustache

I would like to implement a lambda in java that can be called from a mustache template. So far, I've only been able to find a poorly written blog article about this subject: https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/21/the-joy-of-mustache-server-side-templates-for-the-jvm. Essentially, I have a template file

```
{{#getContentType}}
     {{http-response.headers}}
{{/getContentType}}
```

The method name is `getContentType` it takes a list object `http-response.headers` and returns the value from the key-value pair

```
{
    "name": "Content-Type",
    "value": "application/json"
}
```

I have even looked at the documentation: https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java#readmehttps://github.com/spullara/mustache.java#readme, but I am still struggling to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For reference an example input for the `getContentType` lambda would like

```
[
            {
                "name": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "name": "Content-Length",
                "value": "363"
            },
            {
                "name": "Authorization",
                "value": "Bearer bearerToken"
            },
            {
                "name": "Host",
                "value": "host"
            }
        ]
```

There aren't any examples of using TemplateFunctions, but the documentation is here:http://spullara.github.io/mustache/apidocs/. It's pretty hard for a new person to "just get it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by referring to the Spring Docs on lambda functions. The problem is that they have a typo, it says "lamba" not lambda: https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#working-with-asciidoctor-customizing-tables-formatting-problems.

Going off of the tabelCellContent lambda function. I found an example in the tests for `StandardWriterReslover`. https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.StandardWriterResolver.

The lambda function is added to the map `templateContext`:

```
Map<String, Object> templateContext = new HashMap<>();
    templateContext.put("tableCellContent",
        new AsciidoctorTableCellContentLambda());
```

The class for AsciidoctorTableCellContentLambda looks like:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014-2016 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.restdocs.templates.mustache;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

import org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Mustache.Lambda;
import org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template.Fragment;

/**
 * A {@link Lambda} that escapes {@code |} characters so that the do not break the table's
 * formatting.
 *
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 * @since 1.1.0
 */
public final class AsciidoctorTableCellContentLambda implements Lambda {

    @Override
    public void execute(Fragment fragment, Writer writer) throws IOException {
        String output = fragment.execute();
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length(); i++) {
            char current = output.charAt(i);
            if (current == '|' && (i == 0 || output.charAt(i - 1) != '\\')) {
                writer.append('\\');
            }
            writer.append(current);
        }
    }

}
```